# Removing data attributes from HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to get this one to work...

I have a page that hides certain links. When the DOM is loaded, I'm using jQuery to toggle some of those elements.  This is driven by using a data attribute like so:

```
<div class="d_btn" data-usr='48'>
  <div class="hidden_button">
```

Then, I have the code:

```
  $.each($(".d_btn"), function() {
     var btn = $(this).data('usr');
   if ( btn == '48' ){      
     $(this).children('.hidden_button').toggle();
   }
```

The above all works as planned.  The problem is that I am trying to remove the data-usr from the class .d_btn once the if statement is evaluated.  I've tried the following and nothing works (i.e., after the page is loaded, the source still shows the data-usr attribute:

```
$(this).removeAttr("data-usr");

$(this).removeData("usr");
```

I've been working on this for a couple of hours now and...nothing!  Help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I've tried the great suggestions of setting the data attribute to an empty string but I'm still not getting the desired result.

To explain a little further, The reason I'm trying to remove the attribute is so when an ajax response adds another item to the page, the previously added items would already have the button either shown or hidden.  Upon AJAX response, I'm calling the same function once the DOM is loaded.

Currently, when something is added via AJAX, it toggles all the buttons (showing the ones that were hidden and vice versa.)  Ugh...

I'm also fully willing to try alternatives to my approach.  Thanks!

***UPDATE***

Well, the light bulb just flashed and I am able to do what I want to do by just using .show() instead of .toggle()

Anyway, I'd still like to find an answer to this question because the page will be potentially checking hundreds of items whenever something is added - this seems horribly inefficient (even for a computer, hahaha.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the DOM doesn't affect the source. It affects the DOM, which you can view with the Inspector/Developer Tools. Right click => View Source will give you the original source of the page, not the actual current source as modified by JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks - that is really helpful!  I've updated my post with additional information.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you set the value to a random value or empty variable instead if removeAttr does not work..

```
$(this).attr("data-usr" , '');

$(this).prop("data-usr" , '');
```

Comment: But when the data-usr is empty , I guess it won't hit the if loop right.. So the button status for that particular div will not be toggled  .. Can you construct a fiddle if what I am thinking is wrong ??

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but it's not working like that.  Undefined created a fiddle in his response above: jsfiddle.net/VVbFG

Comment: can you update your code with the entire logic that is going on along with the ajax request..

Answer (score 2):

Set it to a blank string:

```
$(this).attr("data-usr", "");
```

I second what Kolink said: check the DOM, not the source. (Chrome: Ctrl + Shift + i).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated. Checking the source will only show the original unedited source for the   webpage. What you need to do is check the DOM using developer tools.

I've just checked everything in Chrome's inspector on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rXGZa/) and the attribute is definitely being removed as well as the data.

Comment: Thanks - Then perhaps there's a problem with my reasoning?  Unfortunately I don't know how to check the DOM (tried on firebug and couldn't make heads or tails out of anything)...

Comment: In Firefox you should be able to right click on the element in the page and select "Inspect Element with Firebug". You'll then see the markup for the page localized at the element you selected.

Comment: Nice - ^ Thanks buddy ^ I just checked and you're correct - the data attribute is removed.  Which confirms my conclusion that it was a problem with my reasoning.  Question now is why, when a new item is added via AJAX and I call the same function, is the loop run on all of the items and everything is toggled?

Comment: Hmmm... Are you adding just one instance or are you overwriting all the html? Could you post a more complete sample of your code in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks again - Unfortunately, there's not much more to post...  When the AJAX response is returned, the same partial (template) is used as when the page originally loaded.  I thought that by removing the data elements after the if statement is run, when calling the unhide function on the newly added elements, it would skip over the original items.  But, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case.  For some reason it seems the data is still bound to the DOM element (even though we can't see it with inspection.)  I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

> (i.e., after the page is loaded, the source still shows the data-usr attribute:

the source will always show what was initially loaded on the page, and not the current state of the DOM element.  If you inspect the page in your console, you should see the attribute disapear.

I use and have tested,

```js
$button.removeAttr("data-usr");
```

and it works as expected.  An inspection of the DOM reveals the `data-usr` is no longer an attribute.