# How to remove data-toggle="dropdown" and data-hover="dropdown" using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to remove  `data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"` from this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"  >Hello</a>
```

using jquery?

Comment: Please provide your html and detailed information.

Comment: Check the answer to the following question it could give you an idea what to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522293/removing-data-attributes-from-html-using-jquery

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
removeAttr('data-toggle');
removeAttr('data-hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) used to remove attribute

Answer (score 0):

As suggested use `removeAttr` to remove and `attr` to add it again

To remove title attribute from an input with class `input`:

```
$('.input').removeAttr( "title" )
```

and to add again:

```
$('.input').attr( "title", "my title text");
```

Answer (score 0):

This
    data-toggle="dropdown" and  data-hover="dropdown"
Where HTML 5 data- Attributes.

Here is the code to remove require data- attribute that you want to remove from multiple data- attribute.

**[Chick Here for Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpqh5/15/)**

HTML

```
<div id="me"><a id='me1' title="title" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-Sample="test1" >Hello</a></div>

Before:<br>
<div id="before"></div>

After<br>
<div id="after"></div>
```

JQ

```
var data = $("a").data();

var keys = $.map(data , function(value, key) {   return key; });

$("#before").text($("#me").html());

for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
// here you can remove data- attribute that you want to remove from multiple data- attribute
// here you can add 'if' condition for any For data- attribute you want to remove
    if (keys[i].indexOf('toggle') != -1 || keys[i].indexOf('hover') != -1) {
    $("a").removeAttr("data-" + keys[i]);
    }

}
$("#after").text($("#me").html());
```

Here is the **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpqh5/15/)**

if this help's you Reply me Dude..